# Transactional Replication Error adding new subscription (null) article

Tags: sql-server-2008, transactional-replication

When attempting to add a new subscription to an existing Transactional publication on 2008. It is all configured on 1 server as it is for Pre-Production testing.

I get the following error when attempting to create the new subscription.

```
Msg 20027, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_MSadd_subscription, Line 223
The article '(null)' does not exist.
Msg 14070, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MSrepl_changesubstatus, Line 1208
Could not update the distribution database subscription table. The subscription status could not be changed.
Msg 14057, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MSrepl_addsubscription_article, Line 383
The subscription could not be created.
```

Comment: Can you give us more details? What is the article that you added to this publication?

Comment: I didn't add an article. I added another subscription to the publication that was already running. I would love to find out which article has somehow become (NULL)

Comment: --read to fast, sorry--